# EF6 foreign key definition

Tags: entity-framework

To define a foreign key as I know, I have only reference the field like explained in [this text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-2) :

```
   public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

But for me this approach is not working and I need use a code like this :

```
[ForeignKey("MyFkName")]
public virtual ForeignKeyTable ForeignKeyProperty { get; set; }
public int? MyFkName{ get; set; }
```

What I'm doing wrong please ?

Comment: *What* is not working? There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Did you add the Author class and give it an Id?

Comment: Hi, if I use just :  public int MyFkProperty { get; set; } to create the fk, the table is created just with an INT column tha's is not a foreign key

Comment: OK, what exactly to you refer to when you say "this approach"? Seems to me now it's the second code fragment. That "doesn't work" because EF can't match the name of the foreign key and the reference by its name conventions. You have to add an explicit mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you forgot to declare your Author property **virtual**;

```
// a Book belongs to exactly one Author using Foreign Key:
public int AuthorId {get; set;}
public virtual Author Author {get; set;}
```

Furthermore your Author should have a reference to the Books it has:

```
// Every Author has zero or more Books:
public ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
```

This is all that is needed to inform entity framework that you are modelling a one-to-many relationship

That your `Author` property should be declared virtual makes sense. After all, your Book doesn't have the Author data readily available as data.

When addressing one of the properties in `Book.Author`, entity framework has to create a join query instead of returning data.

Hence the `Author` in the Author property isn't a real `Author`, but an object derived from `Author` that knows how to get the `Author` data of the `Book` from the database.

Comment: Ok, if I use  pubic virtual Author Author {get; set;} the fk is created ok. But at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-2 , as I can understand, the author says that the navigation property (  pubic virtual Author Author {get; set;} ) is optional...

Comment: I tried it without the virtual, and it didn't work. As I wrote, the virtual makes sense. Sometimes you just fill in Book.Author = new Author() {...}, which means that the Author is just some data. But if you perform a DbSet query and use Book.Author, this is internally a Linq join operation. This can't work without being virtual